# Insecure Docker registry and self-signed certificates

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, self-signed, k3s

I have already setup a localized docker registry with self-signed certificates based on this reference: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry.

I pussed an example image using:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
sudo docker tag hello-world registry.local.doc:5045/hello-world
sudo docker push registry.local.doc:5045/hello-world
```

I am able to see the "contents" of the registry on https://registry.local.doc:5045/v2/_catalog:

{"repositories":["hello-world"]}

**1st Problem**

I have used self-signed certificates using:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout ./certs/tls.key -x509 -days 365  -subj "/C=GR/ST=./L=./O=./CN=registry.local.doc" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:registry.local.doc" -out ./certs/tls.crt
```

However, in order to make it work I have to add in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` the following:

> {   "insecure-registries" : ["registry.local.doc:5000"] }

which is confusing as I am using self-signed certificates as already mentioned.

**2nd Problem**

I have a k3s node and I want to pull images from inside a Pod.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: registry-test
  labels:
    app: registry-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: registry-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: registry-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: registry-test
        image: registry.local.doc:5045/hello-world
```

It works but first I need to run:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
sudo systemctl restart containerd
sudo systemctl restart k3s
```

I understand the reasons behind the execution of the first two commnads `sudo update-ca-certificates` & `sudo systemctl restart containerd`, however I have no clue why I have to run `sudo systemctl restart k3s` to make it works.

Is there a solution without restarting the cluster, as something like this is forbidden when we talk about a cluster in production?

And if I had a k8s cluster, what exactly would Ι have to restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Problem**
registry is a server side, your docker is client side, the config `insecure-registries` tell your docker to skip server cert validation.
Without this settings, docker will not pull image because the cert is invalid.

**2st Problem**
you need to restart k3s only because you using `insecure-registries` config. docker need restart to reload this config.

When you using self-sign cert registry, you have two way to pull image from there.

1. Add `{ "insecure-registries" : ["registry.local.doc:5000"] }` to /etc/docker/daemon.json and restart k3s

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart containerd
   sudo systemctl restart k3s
   ```

   In production, normally you should have more then one worker and follow below step:

   1. drain the worker, see doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/). This will move your pod to other worker.
   2. add insecure-registries and restart k3s.
   3. uncordon the worker, pod can move back to this worker.
   4. repeat above step on every worker.
2. Add your self-sign cert to trust store on every woker. This way don't require restart k3s.
   For ubuntu see below.

   ```bash
   sudo cp tls.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
   sudo update-ca-certificates
   ```
3. add cert to docker certs folder

   > Instruct every Docker daemon to trust that certificate. The way to do this depends on your OS.
   > Linux: Copy the domain.crt file to /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistrydomain.com:5000/ca.crt on every Docker host. You do not need to restart Docker.

   ```bash
   sudo cp tls.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.local.doc:5000/ca.crt
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To sum up, what you propose is to remove registry.local.doc:5000 from insecure-registries and in each worker to do sudo cp tls.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and sudo update-ca-certificates?

Comment: this does not work either. I copy my certificate in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and again it raises the same error

Comment: I added one more method, try it.